# how to show images back from database that are saved in public images directory laravel

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

i am stuck on it for a while now something obvious is missing but can't find it out on the moment [i am trying to retrieve the images by the loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAHo5.jpg) i am trying to retrieve the images by the loop

that's the code for saving it which is working fine. 
[code to save the image]

here's what i get when i try to get it out [404 error upon retriveing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u60DT.jpg)

Comment: Can you share you code for `Tour` class? and also how do you save the image in database?

Comment: check if your images folder is under travel/public/admin folder, if not, change the way you are rendering your assets

Comment: here is the (Tour class code)
class Tour extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','location','contact','photo_id','service','description',
    ];

    public function photo(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Photo');
    }

Comment: @CodeIsLife my images are in public images folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your image path is **public/images/404.png** i guess 
use `asset` or `url`

```
<img src="{{$tour->photo->file ? asset('images/'.$tour->photo->file): asset('images/404.png')}}">

<img src="{{$tour->photo->file ? url('images/'.$tour->photo->file): url('images/404.png')}}">
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for showing response on my post, really appreciate all of your support :) stay blessed  @Hamel Raj thanks man, for the answer. it worked. :)